# Vue Router 2 breaks links

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

For some reason my vue-router breaks links.
For example, when I setup `<router-link to="/user/bar">...` I've got this in url:

```
/http:/siteexample.com/user/bar
```

this should be `http://` instead `/http:/`

So, why urls are not formatted properly?

My routes example:

```
var routes = [
    {path      : '/user/', component: Network},
    {path      : '/user/foo', component: Foo},
    {path      : '/user/bar', component: Bar},
    {path      : '*', component: Notfound}
];

var router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes
});
```

**UPD:**

Actually its ok, but problem was - my urls becomes like that: `http://siteexample.com/http:/siteexample.com/user/bar`

I've replaced this line in vue-router.js

```
pushState(cleanPath(this$1.base + route.fullPath))
```

to

```
pushState(cleanPath(route.fullPath))
```

in
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/dist/vue-router.js#L1682-L1690

And now all works fine, but I'm not sure - is this is a bug or not.

Comment: Do you getting any exception in console ? And try to get rid of history mode, it require some adjustments on server side.

Comment: `{path      : '/user', component: Network},` don't put slash at the end of path

Answer (score 0):

The problem was - `<base href="/">` tag in head.
Remove it and all will be fine.